# End-to-end exactly once semantics in spark structured streaming

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to understand if end-to-end exactly once semantics is compromised in spark structured streaming in the below scenario.

Scenario: Structured streaming job with kafka source and file sink is started. Kafka has 16 partitions and I am reading with 16 executors. I interrupted the job at the moment when a particular batch is incomplete. 8 out of 16 tasks completed and we have 8 output files generated. Now if I run the job again the batch starts and reads the data from the same offset range of previous incomplete batch producing 16 output files. Now the 8 output files of incomplete batch resulted in duplicates and the same has been confirmed by data comparision.

Answer (score 1):

About Streaming end-to-end Exactly-Once, recommand u to read [this poster](https://data-artisans.com/blog/end-to-end-exactly-once-processing-apache-flink-apache-kafka) on flink ( a similar framework with spark ) .

Briefly, store source/sink state when occurring checkpoint event.

> rest of anwser from flink post.

So let’s put all of these different pieces together:

- Once all of the operators complete their pre-commit, they issue a commit .
- If at least one pre-commit fails, all others are aborted, and we roll back to the previous successfully-completed checkpoint.
- After a successful pre-commit, the commit must be guaranteed to eventually succeed — both our operators and our external system need to make this guarantee. If a commit fails (for example, due to an intermittent network issue), the entire Flink application fails, the application restarts according to the user’s restart strategy, and there is another commit attempt. This process is critical because if the commit does not eventually succeed, data loss occurs.